# How to join multiple project with same structure

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, entity-framework

> I want to join multiple project (not assembly) with same structure, For example:

Project1 Layers:

> Project.Project1.Domain - Project.Project1.Data -
>   Projaect.Project1.Service - Project.Project1.UI.Web

Project2 Layers:

> Project.Project2.Domain - Project.Project2.Data -
>   Projaect.Project2.Service - Project.Project2.UI.Web

and ....

I have EntityFramework in Data layer and asp.net mvc for UI.Web layer.
I've made these projects in different teams.

Comment: Could you specify the goal that are you trying to achieve by joining the projects, so it would be easier to give an answer other than "It depends..".

Comment: @Christian two project for example `Online Accounting` and `New Forum' made by different teams.I want joining these two projects together in a solution.

Comment: Do these projects have a common Database?

Comment: @Christian ,Each database is different and just have the same user table

Comment: @Christian i use same database and same user table

Comment: This is a bizarre question! Why not just include all of the projects from solution 2 in solution 1?!? Also if only the user table is the same you could pull it out and create a common web service/api tat does all of the user stuff.